# Unable to upload photos in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, upload, ipad

We have been having trouble directly uploading photos from an iPad to a health care application within Google Chrome.

We were able to directly upload before and suddenly we have been getting an error in Google Chrome:

"The photo upload encountered a problem. Please try uploading the photo again, or select a different image file, before submitting the document."

If we save the same image to a drive on the computer, it uploads fine, but we want to be able to directly upload images from the iPad to the application in Google Chrome.

Sometimes users have to upload 10+ images at a time, and it can be cumbersome for them to first save to the computer drive and then upload.

The direct upload from the iPad to a browser works perfectly fine in IE 11, but the application does not work well with IE (users have been losing their work).

Has anyone had this issue before?

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: With no detailed description of the exact problem you are having no one can answer. "having trouble" tells us nothing we can use to solve the problem.

Comment: When we go to upload the photo into the application from the iPad, an error pops up, as I had said in my post. The exact error is "This photo cannot be uploaded. Please try a different image"